# Not able to load the child record properly from XML using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have two entities as

```
public class DbServer
    {
        public int ServerId { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string Address { set; get; }
        public List<DbDetail> DbDetails = new List<DbDetail>();
    }
    public class DbDetail
    {
        public int DbId { set; get; }
        public string DbName { set; get; }
        public string UserName { set; get; }
        public string PassWord { set; get; }
        public List<string> ConfiguredRules = new List<string>();

    }
```

and the XML file is as under

```
<DataBaseServers>
      <DataBaseServer id ="1" title="IISDevdb1" address="iisdevdb1.mcafee.int\iisdevdb1,1515">
        <DataBases>
          <database id="1" name="ebiz" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="2" name="oneclick" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="3" name="EbizStats" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="4" name="ebizlite" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="5" name="EbizErrors" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="6" name="machinetracker" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="7" name="mast" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="8" name="subscribe" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="9" name="OFFER" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="10" name="Session" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="11" name="Reconciliation" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="12" name="smartmessaging" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="13" name="Payment" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="46" name="SQLEye" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>
          <database id="50" name="VCAPI" userID="se_user" password="se_user_pw!"> </database>         
        </DataBases>
      </DataBaseServer>
      <DataBaseServer id ="3" title="172.16.216.232" address="172.16.216.232">
        <DataBases>
          <database id="34" name="ebiz" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>
          <database id="35" name="oneclick" userID="ebizsol1click" password="ebizsol1click_pw"> </database>
          <database id="36" name="EbizStats" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>
          <database id="37" name="ebizlite" userID="ebizlite" password="ebizlite_pw"> </database>
          <database id="38" name="EbizErrors" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>
          <database id="39" name="machinetracker" userID="mtrackuser" password="mtrackUser_pw"> </database>
          <database id="40" name="mast" userID="mast_user" password="mast_user_pw"> </database>
          <database id="41" name="subscribe" userID="subscribeuser" password="subscribeuser"> </database>
          <database id="42" name="OFFER" userID="offer" password="offer_pw"> </database>
          <database id="43" name="Session" userID="Session" password="session_pw"> </database>
          <database id="44" name="smartmessaging" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>
          <database id="45" name="Payment" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>
          <database id="47" name="monitoring" userID="ebizsol" password="ebizsol_pw"> </database>          
        </DataBases>
      </DataBaseServer>      
    </DataBaseServers>
```

I am trying to populate both the entities as under

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(dbServerPath);
var res = from dbServer in xdoc.Descendants("DataBaseServer")
                     select new DbServer
                     {
                         ServerId = Convert.ToInt32(dbServer.Attribute("id").Value),
                         Name = dbServer.Attribute("title").Value,
                         Address = dbServer.Attribute("address").Value,
                          DbDetails = (from dbDetail in xdoc.Descendants("DataBases")
                                       select new DbDetail
                                       {
                                           DbId = Convert.ToInt32(dbDetail.Attribute("id").Value),
                                           DbName = dbDetail.Attribute("name").Value
                                       }).ToList()

                     };
```

but DBDetails is not getting populated properly.(Object reference error is throwing).

How to rectify that?

Comment: DbDetails is being populated from xdoc2.Descendants but you dont decalre xdoc2 anywhere.

Comment: Sorry but that's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fixed typo the following will work to give you what you need.

```
XElement xdoc = XDocument.Load("dbServerPath").Element("DataBaseServers");
var res = from dbServer in xdoc.Elements("DataBaseServer")
    select new DbServer
    {
        ServerId = Convert.ToInt32(dbServer.Attribute("id").Value),
        Name = dbServer.Attribute("title").Value,
        Address = dbServer.Attribute("address").Value,
        DbDetails = (from dbDetail in dbServer.Element("DataBases").Elements("database")
                     select new DbDetail
                     {
                         DbId = Convert.ToInt32(dbDetail.Attribute("id").Value),
                         DbName = dbDetail.Attribute("name").Value 
                     }).ToList()
    };
```

The reason your code does not work is because when you load the document and then start your linq query you are checking for DataBaseServer elements but at the level you are searching they dont exist so you need to get the DataBaseServers element first and then load the servers from that point.  The same logic applies to the database details population - you need to get the first element that contains all of the database detail records.

Comment: XElement xdoc = XDocument.Load("Test.xml").Element("DataBaseServers");
 is coming as null and hence throwing null refeence exception

Comment: You need to replace Test.xml with your actual xml file. Answer updated to reflect this.